# How to calculate School Year in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

the below is the Date of Birth range to calculate the school year:
I am looking to check which school year child had an appointment, if the appointment was last year, then display the school year the child was in last year?

```
RECEPTION   1/9/15—31/8/16
YEAR 1      1/9/14—31/8/15
YEAR 2      1/9/13—31/8/14
YEAR 3      1/9/12–31/8/13
YEAR 4      1/9/11—31/8/12
YEAR 5      1/9/10—31/8/11
YEAR 6      1/9/09—31/8/10
YEAR 7      1/9/08—31/8/09
YEAR 8      1/9/07—31/8/08
YEAR 9      1/9/06–31/8/07
YEAR 10     1/9/05—31/8/06
YEAR 11     1/9/04—31/8/05
YEAR 12     1/9/03—31/8/04
YEAR 13     1/9/02—31/8/03
```

I have tried this so far, I can get what year the child is currently in, but unable to calculate which school year the child was when had an appointment.

```
,CASE 
  WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='0' THEN 'Reception'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='1' THEN 'Year 1'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='2' THEN 'Year 2'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='3' THEN 'Year 3'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='4' THEN 'Year 4'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='5' THEN 'Year 5'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='6' THEN 'Year 6'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='7' THEN 'Year 7'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='8' THEN 'Year 8'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='9' THEN 'Year 9'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='10' THEN 'Year 10'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='11' THEN 'Year 11'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='12' THEN 'Year 12'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))='13' THEN 'Year 13'
    WHEN (datepart(year,getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,dd.[Date of Birth]) >8) THEN (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+5) 
    ELSE (datepart(Year,dd.[Date of Birth])+4) END))>'13' THEN 'Above Year 13'
    ELSE 'Not in School' end
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is an appointment?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.